# Spacetime Diagram for Robertson-Walker Universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

For the Robertson Walker universe with metric
$$ds^2 = -dt^2 +a(t)[dx^2+dy^2+dz^2]$$
where $a(t)=t^q$ and $0<q<1$, the light cones in the spacetime diagram are drawn as follow:[image]

From the diagram, it seems that the light cones tangent to $t=0$ will eventually intersect each other if we  extend them even further. Why then do we say that pasts of two points may be overlapping?

Comment: $t=0$ isn't defined for this spacetime

Comment: It isn't quite clear (to me), what you are trying to ask. Could you maybe elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It is not trivial to see this from the description given by Sean Carroll. The FRW metric, as you have mentioned, can have a simple solution $a = t^p$ for $(0<q<1)$. (The metric you have given only have a(t) instead of $a^2(t)$) We see that, for $t\rightarrow 0$, the scale factor vanishes. But this does not answer your question of why the light cones do not meet as $t\rightarrow 0$.

So, we need to calculate how the slope of light cone varies in the limit of vanishing $t$. For null paths, (considering only direction $x$), the slope of the cone is given by
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = 0 = -dt^2 + a^2(t)dx^2 \implies \frac{dx}{dt} = \pm \frac{1}{t^q}
\end{equation}

Now you see that, for $t=0 $, there is a singularity (a timelike singularity). We cannot take $q=0$ because of the definition. If we could take $q=0$, then there would be no singularity. Because of the allowed values of q, the light cone are tangent to singularity. That is for a small $t>0$ you have a asymptotic tangent. This marks the geodesic incompleteness such that the null geodesics cannot be extended to the past.

The trick is, we can do a conformal transformation and see that, even though the light cone slope go tangential in coordinate time ($\tau$), we would need finite conformal time to reach the singularity. This marks the particle horizon (by definition). See the picture [here](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept03/Trodden/Trodden2_5.html). There are other worldlines of particles which do not intersect the past of the cone.